# How to print a combination of words one from first array the second from second array and third from third array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, combinations

I want this code to output the following it has three Array List Entries separated by commas as its delimiter `("slow,steady"),("blue, white,green")("whale, shark ");`.It has to output the following

```
slow blue whale 
slow white whale 
slow white shark 
steady blue whale 
steady white shark 
and so forth.
```

I am able to separate each of the words and put them in three separate lists. list1 contains slow steady list2 contains blue white green and list3 contains whale shark . But I am not able to concatenate them.Any inputs are welcome.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;  
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;  

public class HelloWorld {    

    String input;   //input String  
    StringBuffer output;  //Holds the output  
    String delimiter = ","; //Delimiter (default comma (,))  
    String arrayOfWords[];  
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    int listCount;

    /* 
     * Generates combinations by applying the  
     * concept of recursion 
     */  


    public void generateCombinations(String input, String delimiter,int listCount)   
    {       
          output = new StringBuffer();             
          this.input = input;    
          this.delimiter = delimiter;  
          this.listCount = listCount;

                 String[] stockArr = new String[list1.size()];
                 String[] stockArr1 = new String[list2.size()];
                 String[] stockArr2 = new String[list2.size()];

             if(listCount == 1) {
              String items1[] = input.split(",");
               for(int i=0;i< items1.length; i++){

                 list1.add(items1[i]);
               }

             }

             else if(listCount == 2) {
               String items2[] = input.split(",");
               for(int i=0;i< items2.length; i++){

                 //System.out.println(items2[i]);
                 list2.add(items2[i]);
               }

             }

             else {
              String items3[] = input.split(",");
               for(int i=0;i< items3.length; i++){

                // System.out.println(items3[i]);
                 list3.add(items3[i]);
               }

             }


         stockArr = list1.toArray(stockArr);
         stockArr1 = list2.toArray(stockArr1);
         stockArr2 = list3.toArray(stockArr2);


      for(String s1 : stockArr){

             System.out.print(s1);         
      }        


      for(String s2 : stockArr1){

             System.out.print(s2);     
    }        



      for(String s3 : stockArr2){

             System.out.print(s3);       
      }        


      for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
        String s1 = list1.get(i).toString();
              for(int j=0;j<list2.size();j++){
                    String s2 = list2.get(j).toString();
                     System.out.println(s1+s2);
              }


     }


 }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        ArrayList <String> strings = new ArrayList <String>();
        int i=1;

        for(String string : strings){
        new HelloWorld().generateCombinations(string , ",",i);  
            ++i;
        }

    }    
}
```

Comment: So, you want to create one giant string at the end?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.What I am trying to print is : slow blue whale -- line 1 slow white whale -- line 2 and so forth all in separate lines

Comment: Is there any pattern?

Comment: Thanks Uma Kanth for the reply .The pattern is the one edited by you in the question slow blue whale 
slow white whale 
slow white shark 
steady blue whale 
steady white shark 
and so forth. I am not able specify line breaks in the comment

Comment: @Shravya i added my solution without using your code.. please give a try and let me know. Not sure if you want to use recursion..

Comment: @ bakki Thanks a lot.Tried it out.Works too. Without recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had it working good :)
Bonus : Now, it doesn't matter how many words you need to concatenate.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {

    public static void generateCombinations(ArrayList <String> strings, String delimiter){

        int stringsSize = strings.size();
        int i=0;
        String text = "";
        parseList(text, stringsSize ,i, strings, delimiter);

    }

    public static void parseList(String text, int stringsSize, int i,    ArrayList <String> strings, String delimiter) {
        String stringStream = strings.get(i);
        String[] list = stringStream.split(delimiter);
        if (i==stringsSize-1) {
            for (String string : list){
                System.out.println(text + " " + string.replaceAll("\\s+",""));
            }
        } else {
            for (String string : list){
                String text2 = text + " " + string.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                int j = i+1;
                parseList(text2, stringsSize, j, strings, delimiter);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        ArrayList <String> strings = new ArrayList <String>();
        strings.add("slow,steady");
        strings.add("blue, white, green");
        strings.add("whale, shark ");

        generateCombinations(strings , ",");  

    }  
}
```

Results in :

```
 slow blue whale
 slow blue shark
 slow white whale
 slow white shark
 slow green whale
 slow green shark
 steady blue whale
 steady blue shark
 steady white whale
 steady white shark
 steady green whale
 steady green shark
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I tried it.It works perfectly.The concept of recursion seems to fit in perfectly here.

Comment: No problem.I just had one question I was not able to figure it what was the problem in my code when I was trying to print it via for loop. Any idea.May be the list was getting re-initialized to null every time ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using nested `for` loops. In your case 3 layers.

```
    stockArr = list1.toArray(stockArr);
    stockArr1 = list2.toArray(stockArr1);
    stockArr2 = list3.toArray(stockArr2);

    for (String a : stockArr) {
        for (String b : stockArr1) {
            for (String c : stockArr2) {
                System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, it's always more performant if you use `StringBuilder` to concat multiple `String`. i.e.

```
    for (String a : stockArr) {
        for (String b : stockArr1) {
            for (String c : stockArr2) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(a)
                  .append(" ")
                  .append(b)
                  .append(" ")
                  .append(c);
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I added the third for loop too but itsn't printing the three layers.It is printing blank

Comment: I would note that it isnt __always__ more performant. It depends on the situation and benchmarking needs to be done to accurately determine efficiency.

Comment: Add this to remove blanks : sb.append(myWord.replaceAll("\\s+",""))

Comment: Ling Zhong Tried the second one but displays nothing

Comment: Any inputs people.Tried everything specified here . But it is not printing the for loop mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String[]> afterSplit = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    afterSplit.add("slow, steady".split(","));
    afterSplit.add("blue, white, green".split(","));
    afterSplit.add("whale, shark ".split(","));
    for (int i = 0; i < afterSplit.get(0).length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < afterSplit.get(1).length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < afterSplit.get(2).length; k++) {
                System.out.println(afterSplit.get(0)[i].trim() + " "
                        + afterSplit.get(1)[j].trim() + " "
                        + afterSplit.get(2)[k]);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This one works too.But if only three strings are present.Thanks though